# ¿Hay convención de nombres para URL o carpetas de API con respecto a las versiones?

Tags: php, api

Yo tengo mi pequeña API montada en mi propio servidor remoto.

Cuando empecé a programarla leí que convenía separar el contenido por versiones, de modo que tengo las carpetas organizadas así:

- `example.com/api/v1/endpoint  ...`

Ahora yo estoy haciendo algunas modificaciones intermedias en el código, y he decidido que cuando esos cambios estén listos la API pase a su versión `1.1`.

Mi duda es en cuanto a la convención de nombres:

- No puedo usar `v11` porque eso estaría reservado a la versión `11`
- Puedo usar algo como `v_1_1` o `v1_1`
- O, para guardar uniformidad cuando lleguemos a la versión `10`, usar `v_01_01` o bien `v01_01`

El hecho es que todas me parecen URLs poco estéticas y quiero saber si existe alguna documentación a la cual referirme sobre convención de nombre para APIs donde se den algunas posibilidades y recomendaciones para nombrar la versión.

Estoy usando PHP, por si sirve de algo. Y las peticiones son enviadas desde una aplicación en Android (y en un futuro desde iOs también) mediante URLs como `example.com/api/v1/endpoint`.

He leído algunas fuentes como:

- [Are there any naming convention guidelines for REST APIs?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/778203/5587982)
- [Resource Naming](https://www.restapitutorial.com/lessons/restfulresourcenaming.html)

Otra idea que se me ocurre sería, en vez de usar números de versiones, darle un nombre a cada versión y usar ese nombre en la URL. Por ejemplo:

- `example.com/api/genesis/endpoint`           `.......>    v. 1.0`
- `example.com/api/archangelis/endpoint`           `...>    v. 1.1`

No sé si eso entre dentro del estándar de convención de nombre para APIs.

**NOTA:** No es una pregunta en la que se busquen respuestas basadas en opiniones sino alguna respuesta que muestre algunas posibilidades para aplicar una convención de nombre coherente en cuanto a la versión de una API.

Comment: Lo que he visto como usuario de apis es que las versiones son siempre enteras: v1, v2, v3. A mi me parece que es lo mas claro.  Ahora bien para subversionar también podes un tamaño fijo para el mayor y para el minor. Por ejemplo 2 para la versión y 2 para el release, que en tu ejemplo quedaría v0102 para la v1.2.

Comment: Si sigues versionamiento semántico, tu API v1.1 debiera ser completamente compatible con la v1.0. Sólo introducirías `breaking_changes` al pasar a la 2.0, en cuyo caso tus URLs podrían llevar el prefijo `v2`

Comment: @amenadiel me parece interesante lo que comentas, ¿podrías explicar mejor? ¿Será entonces que estoy planteando mal mi posible `v. 1.1`? Sería interesante conocer sobre el *versionamiento semántico* y los *breaking changes* y cómo se definen o aplican.

Answer (score 3):

Me explayo sobre mi comentario.

El versionamiento semántico o [semver](https://semver.org/) es un estándar de facto. Es decir, nadie te lo impone y muchos proyectos operan distinto. Sin embargo, herramientas de manejo de paquetes dan por hecho que si tu proyecto depende de otra librería, cuando tú especificas qué version de esa librería necesitas, las vas a definir como si estuviera versionada semánticamente.

Básicamente, la versión de un proyecto se interpreta como:

```
 {REVISIÓN MAYOR}.{REV MENOR}.{PATCH}
```

Pensemos que un proyecto tiene una versión  `1.2.5`. Esto significa:

- Revisión mayor: 1
- Revisión menor: 2
- Patch o Hotfix: 5

Un patch o hotfix es sólo una corrección de bugs, estilo (indentación, linters, prettyficación). Una revisión menor en general indica que añades features nuevos pero todo es retrocompatible. Una revisión mayor indica potenciales cambios incompatibles con la versión anterior.

En los manejadores de paquetes (npm, composer, pip) tú puedes decirle: quiero la versión `1.2.x` donde x me da igual, dame el más reciente. Eso se escribe como `~1.2` o `~1.2.0`. Es común hacer eso porque quieres que al actualizar las dependencias se traiga el parche más reciente.

También si te sientes más arriesgado puedes decirle: "Tráeme de la versión 1 la revisión más reciente: `^1.2.0` o `^1` o `^1.0`, todas significan lo mismo.

Puedes omitir el operador inicial y decirle la versión exacta, puedes admitir un rango entre dos versiónes, o puedes decirle "Quiero exactamente la 1.2.1 o la 1.2.3, no me sirve la 1.2.2". Hay un montón de operadores en semver.org que nunca he ocupado. Los más importantes son `^` y `~`.

Abordando tu pregunta original, al hacer cambios en un API vas aumentanto la versión. Eres libre de ocupar un esquema semi semántico y sólo enumerar usando `{MAYOR}.{MENOR}`. Lo importante es que si introduces un cambio que **rompe compatibilidad** con la revisión anterior, **aumentas la versión mayor**. En otro caso aumentas la menor (o la patch si es que la usas).

En consecuencia, nunca debiera haber un endpoint para la versión 1.1. Hay un endpoint para la versión 1. A medida que pasa el tiempo esa versión puede tener nuevos features pero sigue soportando los métodos y estructura de payload que todas las versiones 1.x.

Cuando finalmente metes un cambio que rompe la compatibilidad, ya sea porque el método espera otros parámetros o devuelve una estructura distinta, ahora sí tiene sentido que uses URLs con prefijo v2.

Todo esto que te he dicho es -nuevamente- un estándar de facto. Una buena práctica, si quieres. Nada más que eso. Proyectos importantes pasan por alto esta convención y usan, por ejemplo, el año actual como {MAYOR}. Cambia el año y actualizan {MAYOR} sin que haya cambios relevantes. Un caso particularlemente llamativo es la librería [random_compat](https://github.com/paragonie/random_compat). Las versiones 2.x soportan PHP 5.x. Cuando decidieron dejar de soportar PHP5 y empezar con PHP7 en adelante, lanzaron la versión `v9.99.99`. Así que si necesitas soporte para PHP5 se instala como

```
composer require paragonie/random_compat:\<9.99
```

El framework de node más difundido para hacer netamente APIs es [Loopback](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/index.html), una especie de express en esteroides. En loopback hay un procedimiento establecido para lo que preguntas: [Versioning your API](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Versioning-your-API.html). Pero, sabes? Todo esto tendría mucho más sentido si dependiendo del prefijo de versión pudieras seguir requiriendo la versión anterior, y sin embargo no he visto que expliquen cómo hacer eso elegantemente.

Lo único que se me ocurre sería tener corriendo ambas versiones (escuchando en puertos distintos) y poner un router delante de la aplicación para dirigir las peticiones a una u otra dependiendo de la URL (nginx sabe hacer ese trabajo con fluidez). Sigue pareciéndome subóptimo.

## Excepciones notables

Como dije, hay librerías y proyectos que se saltan esta convención ya sea por costumbre, porque históricamente han nacido así o porque cambian la nomenclatura para asimilarse a otros referentes de la industria. Algunos ejemplos:

**Ubuntu:**

- Sale 2 veces al año y la nomenclatura es `{AÑO}.{MES}`. Sin embargo, nadie instalaría la versión `^18`, porque la versión `18.10`, pese a contener features que no tiene la `18.04` no es LTS ([Long term support](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/LTS)). Tiene un ciclo de vida de pocos meses vs el ciclo de vida de 5 años que tienen los release LTS. Es más, si un dockerfile estableciera Ubuntu `>=18` instalaría eventualmente la 19.04 y luego la 19.10 con insospechadas consecuencias.

**Node.js**

- Hace varios años [seguían versionamiento semántico](https://nodejs.org/es/download/releases/) (desde el 2011 al 2017 las versiones fueron desde la `0.1.14` al `0.12.18`. Esto, porque entre esos años no introdujeron breaking changes. Sin embargo, luego de que un motor paralelo (io.js) se lanzara como `3.31.74`, la eventual fusión entre los dos motores en un proyecto conjunto los llevó a adoptar una nomenclatura donde {MAYOR} indica LTS si es par y lo contrario si es impar. Cualquier bump a {MENOR} o {PATCH} indican mejoras parciales, pero generalmente un bump a {MAYOR} no implica breaking changes, sino modernizaciones al motor que a veces levantan `deprecation notices` si usas paquetes viejos, pero siguen funcionando. Para asegurar que tu app sea corrida en una versión LTS tú generalmente pones, en el `package.json` una restricción del tipo `{ "engines" : { "node" : "~10 || ~8 || ~6" }}` asegurándote de que proveedores de CI como CircleCI, testing como Travis o PaaS como Heroku usen la más reciente de entre los releases LTS saltándose las versiones impares.

**PHP**

- PHP sigue una numeración que parece semántica pero en realidad puede tener breaking changes en lo que sería MINOR. Hay breaking changes entre la `5.6.x` y la `5.5.x`. Algunos levantan errores del tipo `E_DEPRECATED` y otros de plano rompen la aplicación. Cuando iban a sacar la versión `5.7` decidieron arbitrariamente que había pasado tanto tiempo desde la `5.6` que para reflejar un gran salto al futuro decidieron llamarle `7.0`. De nuevo en este caso la `7.0` introduce deprecation notices sobre métodos, funciones e interfaces respecto a la `5.6` pero además (por ejemplo) la `7.1` introduce más cambios y elimina soporte para funcionalidades de la `5.6`. La `7.2` es todavía más drástica. Uno pensaría que si ha migrado de la `5.6` a la `7.0` resolviendo todas las deprecation notices puede pasar transparentemente a la `7.1`, pero no es así. En PHP cada bump a {MINOR} deja obsoletas más y más funciones o de plano descontinúa algunas y elimina paquetes. El paquete `ext-mbstring` simplemente no existe en PHP 7.2. Al menos, cuando instalas una librería usando `composer` ésta por lo general establece que requiere PHP 7 o superior o bien 5.6 o superior. Por ahí estás parcialmente resguardado.

**Python**

- En el caso de Python, y aunque es un poco una aberración, la mayoría de las distros de Linux traen la 2.x y la 3.x. Como muchas extensiones del escritorio son en realidad librerías de python, algunas tienen bindings para la 2.x y otras para la 3.x y coexisten porque muchas nunca sacaron bindings nativos para la 3. Cuando haces una app en Python lo aconsejado es crear un ambiente virtual (`virtualenv`) dentro del cual todo es 3.x o todo es 2.x. El mismo manejador de paquetes `pip` puede ser un symlink a `pip2` o a `pip3`. Hay muchos tutoriales para levantas un API con `flask` que omiten esta salvedad y terminas intentando instalar paquetes de la versión 3 en un virtualenv que sin querer creaste con `pip2`. Dentro del virtualenv las dependencias sí siguen versionamiento semántico, pero a veces te encuentras con inexplicables conflictos que terminan ocurriendo porque estás en un virtualenv con la versión equivocada. A menudo lo que recomiendan hacer cuando ya te das por vencido es empezar de cero y poner explícitamente `python3 -m pip install <paquete>`, porque el ejecutable `python` puede ser cualquiera de las dos versiones.